# Make div's height to be exact as img inside it

Tags: html, css, sass

I have div and img inside it. How can I make this div to expand with img?

```
<div class="container-fluid banner">
  <img />
  <div class="row text-center banner__div col-xs-12">

  </div>
  <div class="row text-center banner__slider col-xs-12">

  </div>
```

And here is my .scss:

```
.banner{
  position:relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient($gradient-top, $gradient-bottom);
  height: 960px; //I WANT TO GET RID OF IT
  img{
    content:url("../img/banner_bg.png");
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
}
```

Already tried display: inline-block - doesn't work

Comment: `height : 100%` for the div

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a div to be the same height as an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214072/setting-a-div-to-be-the-same-height-as-an-image)

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    width: desired width;
    height: desired height;
}
```

EDIT: End then you put it like this:

```
<div class="wrapper"><img /></div>
```